# datatable not being updated after contextmenu action

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, primefaces

I have this code:

```
            <p:contextMenu for="customersTable">  
            <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="customersTable" icon="ui-icon-close" actionListener="#{customerbean.onDeleteCustomer}"/>  
            </p:contextMenu>  


            <p:dataTable id="customersTable" var="customer" widgetVar="customerTable" value="#{customerbean.customerList}" paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" emptyMessage="#{text['table.customer.filter.notfound']}" filteredValue="#{customerbean.filteredCustomers}" editable="true" draggableColumns="true" rowKey="#{customer.id}" selection="#{customerbean.selectedCustomer}" selectionMode="single">
```

My problem is that when I click on the 'Delete' in the contextMenu, everything is working fine in the sense that the record/row is being erased from the backend through the bean-method invocation however the table is not updated reflecting the new data.

Comment: you have to give the full component id for the datatable for the update attribute like update="formid:datatableid"

Answer (score 1):

you have to provide the full component id for the dataTable while updating.

```
 <h:form id="frm">
  <p:contextMenu for="customersTable">  
        <p:menuitem value="Delete" update="frm:customersTable" icon="ui-icon-close"  actionListener="#{customerbean.onDeleteCustomer}"/>  
        </p:contextMenu>  
        <p:dataTable id="customersTable" var="customer" widgetVar="customerTable"         value="#{customerbean.customerList}" paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" emptyMessage="#{text['table.customer.filter.notfound']}" filteredValue="#{customerbean.filteredCustomers}" editable="true" draggableColumns="true" rowKey="#{customer.id}" selection="#{customerbean.selectedCustomer}" selectionMode="single"> 



 </h:form>
```

Comment: I have set the prependId to false. When I enter the full ID, I get this exception: javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with identifier ba

Comment: can you post the exception please

Comment: I cannot post all of it but it is like I wrote in the previous post: SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/viewCustomerList.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "ba
:customersTable" referenced from "j_idt34".
        at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java
273)
        at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addIds(AjaxRequestBuilder.jav
:102)
        at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.jav
:90)

Comment: oh.. did u check the id of the datatable in firebug?? .. mayb you have a nested form somewhere in the layout.

Comment: No, and I dont get an exception if I only use "customersTable". If I change it to anything else, I get an exception. So I doubt this has to do with this. Furthermore, prependId is set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what the issue was - quite trivial. I was deleting it from the database but not from the Collection which Primefaces uses to render it on the screen. It needs to be deleted from both.

Comment: but why were you getting SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/viewCustomerList.xhtml] javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier "ba :customersTable" referenced from "j_idt34". at ??

Comment: I got that only when following your answer, i.e. that I have to prepend the form-name.